# Change window size of an android activity by Drag and Drop on a window part

Tags: android

I want exactly the same draggable mini window activity for my app like the one present in the app here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oryon.multitaskingpro

One of the images of the feature I need is:
[Multi tasking pro screeny
]https://lh5.ggpht.com/6Y5q2MCyoHPLGnDNwt7oQ2lbQkbkEDEgD16jQF6UbmoRjgSAuNjHZ4h6qcNgrfnVKY8n=h900-rw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the answer.....I got an open source library named **StandOut** to do so.
I anybody else wants to do so can also use above library..its awesome